# Cannot find module 'puppeteer' via cfexecute, but works on cmd

Tags: node.js, npm, coldfusion, puppeteer, cfexecute

Please save my sanity with this.

```
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
Installed Nodejs via executable. This also installed npm
Tested both via cmd with npm -v and node -v. Both found.
Using cmd installed puppeteer using npm install puppeteer@9.0.0 -g
```

Windows environment variables added too
User variables for Administrator, no spaces:

```
Variable:NODE_PATH 
Value:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
Variable:Path Value:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

System variables:

```
Variable: NODE_PATH 
Value:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
Variable: Path 
Value:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
```

Got a test file that I run via cmd like this:
`node c:/home/pm/wwwroot/test_files/puppeteer/connect-and-check.js`

First line within the file:
`const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');`

All is working fine. So CMD related installation is good

Try the same thing via `cfexecute` and it fails on the first line as the module is not found. Full error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer' Require stack: - C:\home\pm\wwwroot\admin\jscripts\puppeteer\ocprocess.js 
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940:15) 
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:773:27) 
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19) 
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18) 
> at Object. (C:\home\pm\wwwroot\admin\jscripts\puppeteer\ocprocess.js:2:19) 
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14) 
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32) 
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14) 
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) 
> { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', 
> requireStack: ['C:\home\pm\wwwroot\admin\jscripts\puppeteer\ocprocess.js' ] }

Any thoughts? The puppeteer module is installed globally (also tried with `--save`, but made no difference), works via command line, but fails via app itself. Worst thing, we got the same setup on another VPS, literally the same versions, environment variables etc. and it is working fine. What am I missing?

Comment: I have something similar to this. I don't call the module directly, I call the node file that imports the module. `<cfexecute name="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" arguments="C:/(rest of your path to Node File)" timeout="59" variable="execution"/> ` Does this help at all?

Comment: Could it be a authorization / rights issue?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, so ended up installing local puppeteer into the project root. Low and behold - everything worked. It must have been authorization/rights issue, but I just could not discover where, or with what.